# How to find the polar dual of $\{(x,y):y\geqslant x^2\}$ in $\Bbb R^2$?

Tags: convex-analysis, duality-theorems

How to find the polar dual of $\{(x,y):y\geqslant x^2\}$ in $\Bbb R^2$?

If the polar dual of a set $A$ is $A^*=\{x\text{ in }\Bbb R^2:ax\leqslant 1\text{ for all }a\text{ in }A\}$.

I study from *convexity* by Roger Webster, Duality p.99. I tried: if $b>0$ then $ax+bx^2 \le ax+by\le 1$. I don't know if I can take $ax+bx^2=1$ then 
$x=(-a\pm \sqrt{a^2+4b})/(2b)$ then we require $a^2+4b$ to be $\ge 0$, i.e., $a^2\ge -4b$, hence $-a^2/(4b)\le 1$.

Comment: See [math notation help](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polar is usually defined as $A^\circ = \{ x | \langle x, a \rangle \le 1, \forall a \in A \}$.

In this case, we have $A^\circ = \{ (a,b) | ax+by \le 1, \forall y \ge x^2 \}$.

Suppose $(a,b) \in A^\circ$. We see that $b \le 0$, since if $b>0$, we would need to have $ax+bx^2 \le 1$ for all $x$ which is impossible.

If $b = 0$, then we see that we must have $a = 0$, otherwise the constraint could be violated for some $x$.

If $b <0$, then we need to find $a$ satisfying $ax+by \le 1$ for all $y \ge x^2$. Since $b<0$, this simplifies to $ax+bx^2 \le 1$ for all $x$. A quick maximization shows that this is true **iff** $-{a^2 \over 4b} \le 1$.

Combining the above we see $A^\circ = \{(a,b) | a^2 \le -4b \}$.

Comment: but how 
since b<0,this simplifies to a*x+b*x^2<=1 for all x 
y>=x^2----->b*y<=b*x^2---->a*x+b*y<=a*x+b*x^2
and we have a*x+b*y<=1
then how a*x+b*x^2<=1 for all x 
and we should apply maximaization to what
Thank you very much in advance
@copper.hat

Comment: If $b<0$, then if $y\ge x^2$, we have $by \le b x^2$. So, if we have $ax+bx^2 \le 1$, we automatically have $ax+by \le 1$  (as long as $y \ge x^2$).

Comment: last queastion please,why you don't write in the solution that the polar of A={(a,b):b<0,$a^2$<=-4*b}

Comment: There is no need and it would not be correct; if a pair satisfies $a^2 \le - 4b$, then we must have $b\le 0$.

Comment: But we can write the polar of the set of A as {(a,b):$a^2$/(-4*b)<=1} and one can say that since $a^2$/(-4*b)<=1 then -$a^2$<=4*b which will make b either positive or negative

Comment: I'm really not sure what you are trying to get at. The point $(0,0)$ is in the polar, and if $a^2 \le -4 b$ we **must** have $b\le 0$ since $a^2 \ge0$.

Answer (score 2):

I would begin with the concept of *support function*, which is defined as follows: for a unit vector $\xi$, $h(\xi) = \sup_{a\in A}( a\cdot \xi)$. Geometrically, this is what you get by projecting $A$ onto the line with direction $\xi$, and taking the point that's furthest away in direction of $\xi$.

The polar dual is formed by $0$ and the points $x\ne 0$ such that $|x|\le \frac{1}{h(x/|x|)}$. You should convince yourself of the following:

1. $h(\xi)=\infty$ when $\xi_2\ge 0 $
2. When $\xi_2<0$, we have $h(\xi) = \max_{t\in \mathbb R} (t,t^2)\cdot (\xi_1,\xi_2)$. Expand the dot product and find the maximum of the function with the calculus tools: find the  derivative, set it to $0$...